# How to download Xcode - iPhone os entire reference library?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, reference-library

Open X code. Go to help menu / or press command + shift + /

Select documentation option.

Now a help window will be opened. In this help window, on the left side there are many options like - iPhone os 2.1 subscribe, iPhone os 2.2 subscribe, iPhone os 3.0 subscribe, Xcode reference subscribe (something look like this).

If we press iPhone os 3.0 subscribe - button, entire iPhone os 3.0 reference library will be downloaded to the osx - current pc only.

I want to download the same "iPhone os 3.0 subscribe", But the thing is - I am not using mac right now. But I still want to download it. Because mac is at my home and my Home mac - doesn't have internet connection and I would like to use this download on my home mac.

I don't know how it would be possible?

Comment: I need something like this. This link downloads xcode3 docs for offline  - http://learning2code.blogspot.com/2008/05/download-xcode-docsets-to-your-hard.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The feeds that Xcode uses to pull the documentation from online are:

- iPhone OS 3.1 -  http://developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiPhone3_1.atom
- Mac OS X 10.6 - http://developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleSnowLeopard.atom
- Dev Tools - http://developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleXcode3_2.atom

Each feed links to ".xar" files (Extensible Archive), which you can download and expand yourself using the [XAR unarchiver](http://code.google.com/p/xar/).  It expands into a .docset bundle, which you can pop open and browse yourself.  The main index.html file is at Contents/Resources/Documents/index.html

Comment: Something Confused. I am right now on windows. I have downloaded the xar unarchiver. But I think it won't work for windows downloading.

Comment: @sagar - Not being an expert on Windows, I can't help you with that.  Perhaps someone on superuser.com can help you build and run xar on Windows.

Comment: Here is the superuser link. http://superuser.com/questions/64116/how-to-download-xcode-documentation/64184#64184

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand very good what you need, but as I think you want to download a entire tree of the web site, for this I suggest you two programs:

- [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) (Free)
- [SurfOffline](http://www.surfoffline.com/) (Shareware)

Comment: No, sir - You misunderstood me. Xcode has facility. Let's take an example. Microsoft .net has msdn for download. same way xcode-iphone-os-3.0 download is also available but I don't know from where exactly should I download it?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm going to let this answer here to help someone other. Ok?

Comment: Ok. No problem. HTTrack is also a good option for offline surfing. It's a light weight application & it can download heavy weight sites.
+1 for HTTrack,