# Where can I find RSS feeds for Xcode Documentation?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos

Occasionally I like to work completely disconnected from a network.  In those cases it's really nice to have complete sets of documentation on my Mac.  Xcode supports subscribing to feeds of documentation.  I've subscribed to the sets that I'm interested in but there's a problem: It doesn't appear that the lists are up to date.

I'd like to subscribe to the feed for 10.6 but I can't find out what the url is.  I've googled and searched through the documentation on developer.apple.com but no luck so far.  Does anyone know what the feed url is for 10.6, or if there's a link that contains a listing of all of the feeds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in Xcode.  Xcode menu > Preferences > Documentation > Click the "i" button next to "Mac OS X 10.6 Core Library", and you'll see the feed url in the info window.

For future reference, it's: http://developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleSnowLeopard.atom

Further information is available in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658707#1658927